# I am not able to get multiple records based on the Search id. It is displaying only one record

Tags: java

Suppose in my table ,  i have CAT, CAMEL,, CAP When i search by 'CA' , it is displaying one record not all records.

in database :

```
public List<Application> getAllapplicationDetails(String name)
 {   
List<Application> app=new ArrayList<Application>();
try
{

 Connection con = null;

  String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
  System.out.println("1 step");
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    System.out.println("2 step");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, "system", "system");
    System.out.println("3 step");      
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from Application where LOWER(name) like '"+ name.toLowerCase()+"%'");
System.out.println("Entering in to the fucntion 2");
ps.execute();
System.out.println("Entering in to the fucntion 13");
ResultSet rs  =ps.getResultSet();
if(rs.next())
{
System.out.println("Entering in to the fucntion 4");
Application abean=new Application();
abean.setName(rs.getString(1));
abean.setApplicationName(rs.getString(2));
abean.setContactNumber(rs.getInt(3));
app.add(abean);
System.out.println("Entering in to the fucntion 1" + app);
}
}
catch(SQLException e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return app;

}
```

In servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        DBConnection db=new DBConnection();
        HttpSession hs = request.getSession();
        String name=request.getParameter("appname");
        List<Details> dbean=db.getAllDetails(name);

        hs.setAttribute("detbean",dbean);
        if(dbean.isEmpty())
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("<caption>Sorry, No Record Found</caption>");
        }
        else
        response.sendRedirect("Application.jsp");
    }
```

In other jsp, i am displaying passing the "apname" keyword and displaying record in other jsp page using list and by passing session from servlet class

But in output , it is displaying only one record. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Well, while you are reading the results, you are using `if(rs.next())`. This will only show the first result. You should use `while(rs.next())` instead, so it can iterate through all elements.

Edit: Are you sure your query returns more than one row? 
Write the following to be sure:

```
int rowcount=0;
if(rs.last())
    rowcount=rs.getRow();

rs.beforeFirst(); //To not miss first item
System.out.println("N rows: "+rowcount);
while(rs.next()) {
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: i used while(rs.next()) , still getting same only 1 record

Comment: Are you sure you are calling your method correctly?